# Two Webpart load usercontrol dynamically connect together

Tags: sharepoint

In `Webpart` connection. I want to provider `webpart` load user-control dynamic, and then transfer a parameter to the second `webpart`, and then second `webpart` load user-control of it with parameter received.

How can I do that?